# How to get notification after transactions completed(php, paypal)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I need to get some notification if my transactions completed so then I can update my database... Curently code works good, the only problem is when bayer completed transaction he get button to redirect to store but don't redirect automaticly....

Here is paypal.class.php :

```
<?php
/*******************************************************************************
 *                      PHP Paypal IPN Integration Class
 *******************************************************************************
 *      Author:     Micah Carrick
 *      Email:      email@micahcarrick.com
 *      Website:    http://www.micahcarrick.com
 *
 *      File:       paypal.class.php
 *      Version:    1.3.0
 *      Copyright:  (c) 2005 - Micah Carrick 
 *                  You are free to use, distribute, and modify this software 
 *                  under the terms of the GNU General Public License.  See the
 *                  included license.txt file.
 *      
 *******************************************************************************
 *  VERION HISTORY:
 *      v1.3.0 [10.10.2005] - Fixed it so that single quotes are handled the 
 *                            right way rather than simple stripping them.  This
 *                            was needed because the user could still put in
 *                            quotes.
 *  
 *      v1.2.1 [06.05.2005] - Fixed typo from previous fix :)
 *
 *      v1.2.0 [05.31.2005] - Added the optional ability to remove all quotes
 *                            from the paypal posts.  The IPN will come back
 *                            invalid sometimes when quotes are used in certian
 *                            fields.
 *
 *      v1.1.0 [05.15.2005] - Revised the form output in the submit_paypal_post
 *                            method to allow non-javascript capable browsers
 *                            to provide a means of manual form submission.
 *
 *      v1.0.0 [04.16.2005] - Initial Version
 *
 *******************************************************************************
 *  DESCRIPTION:
 *
 *      NOTE: See www.micahcarrick.com for the most recent version of this class
 *            along with any applicable sample files and other documentaion.
 *
 *      This file provides a neat and simple method to interface with paypal and
 *      The paypal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) interface.  This file is
 *      NOT intended to make the paypal integration "plug 'n' play". It still
 *      requires the developer (that should be you) to understand the paypal
 *      process and know the variables you want/need to pass to paypal to
 *      achieve what you want.  
 *
 *      This class handles the submission of an order to paypal aswell as the
 *      processing an Instant Payment Notification.
 *  
 *      This code is based on that of the php-toolkit from paypal.  I've taken
 *      the basic principals and put it in to a class so that it is a little
 *      easier--at least for me--to use.  The php-toolkit can be downloaded from
 *      http://sourceforge.net/projects/paypal.
 *      
 *      To submit an order to paypal, have your order form POST to a file with:
 *
 *          $p = new paypal_class;
 *          $p->add_field('business', 'somebody@domain.com');
 *          $p->add_field('first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
 *          ... (add all your fields in the same manor)
 *          $p->submit_paypal_post();
 *
 *      To process an IPN, have your IPN processing file contain:
 *
 *          $p = new paypal_class;
 *          if ($p->validate_ipn()) {
 *          ... (IPN is verified.  Details are in the ipn_data() array)
 *          }
 *
 *
 *      In case you are new to paypal, here is some information to help you:
 *
 *      1. Download and read the Merchant User Manual and Integration Guide from
 *         http://www.paypal.com/en_US/pdf/integration_guide.pdf.  This gives 
 *         you all the information you need including the fields you can pass to
 *         paypal (using add_field() with this class) aswell as all the fields
 *         that are returned in an IPN post (stored in the ipn_data() array in
 *         this class).  It also diagrams the entire transaction process.
 *
 *      2. Create a "sandbox" account for a buyer and a seller.  This is just
 *         a test account(s) that allow you to test your site from both the 
 *         seller and buyer perspective.  The instructions for this is available
 *         at https://developer.paypal.com/ as well as a great forum where you
 *         can ask all your paypal integration questions.  Make sure you follow
 *         all the directions in setting up a sandbox test environment, including
 *         the addition of fake bank accounts and credit cards.
 * 
 *******************************************************************************
*/

class paypal_class {

   var $last_error;                 // holds the last error encountered

   var $ipn_log;                    // bool: log IPN results to text file?

   var $ipn_log_file;               // filename of the IPN log
   var $ipn_response;               // holds the IPN response from paypal   
   var $ipn_data = array();         // array contains the POST values for IPN

   var $fields = array();           // array holds the fields to submit to paypal


   function paypal_class() {

      // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.

      $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

      $this->last_error = '';

      $this->ipn_log_file = '.ipn_results.log';
      $this->ipn_log = true; 
      $this->ipn_response = '';

      // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal
      // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul
      // values can be overwritten by the calling script.

      $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
      $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick'); 

   }

   function add_field($field, $value) {

      // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be 
      // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the 
      // array, it will be overwritten.

      $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
   }

   function submit_paypal_post() {

      // this function actually generates an entire HTML page consisting of
      // a form with hidden elements which is submitted to paypal via the 
      // BODY element's onLoad attribute.  We do this so that you can validate
      // any POST vars from you custom form before submitting to paypal.  So 
      // basically, you'll have your own form which is submitted to your script
      // to validate the data, which in turn calls this function to create
      // another hidden form and submit to paypal.

      // The user will briefly see a message on the screen that reads:
      // "Please wait, your order is being processed..." and then immediately
      // is redirected to paypal.

      echo "<html>\n";
      echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>\n";
      echo "<body onLoad=\"document.forms['paypal_form'].submit();\">\n";
      echo "<center><h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you";
      echo " will be redirected to the paypal website.</h2></center>\n";
      echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"paypal_form\" ";
      echo "action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";

      foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
         echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"/>\n";
      }
      echo "<center><br/><br/>If you are not automatically redirected to ";
      echo "paypal within 5 seconds...<br/><br/>\n";
      echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click Here\"></center>\n";

      echo "</form>\n";
      echo "</body></html>\n";

   }

   function validate_ipn() {

      // parse the paypal URL
      $url_parsed=parse_url($this->paypal_url);        

      // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
      // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
      // script.
      $post_string = '';    
      foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) { 
         $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
         $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&'; 
      }
      $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

      // open the connection to paypal
      $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30); 
      if(!$fp) {

         // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
         // will be in the log.
         $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);       
         return false;

      } else { 

         // Post the data back to paypal
         fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); 

         // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
         while(!feof($fp)) { 
            $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
         } 

         fclose($fp); // close connection

      }

      if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) {

         // Valid IPN transaction.
         $this->log_ipn_results(true);
         return true;       

      } else {

         // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
         $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);   
         return false;

      }

   }

   function log_ipn_results($success) {

      if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off?

      // Timestamp
      $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '; 

      // Success or failure being logged?
      if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
      else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n";

      // Log the POST variables
      $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
      foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
         $text .= "$key=$value, ";
      }

      // Log the response from the paypal server
      $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;

      // Write to log
      $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
      fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n"); 

      fclose($fp);  // close file
   }

   function dump_fields() {

      // Used for debugging, this function will output all the field/value pairs
      // that are currently defined in the instance of the class using the
      // add_field() function.

      echo "<h3>paypal_class->dump_fields() Output:</h3>";
      echo "<table width=\"95%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
            <tr>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Field Name</font></b></td>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Value</font></b></td>
            </tr>"; 

      ksort($this->fields);
      foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
         echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".urldecode($value)."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
      }

      echo "</table><br>"; 
   }
}
```

Here is paypal.php :

```
 <?php

/*  PHP Paypal IPN Integration Class Demonstration File
 *  4.16.2005 - Micah Carrick, email@micahcarrick.com
 *
 *  This file demonstrates the usage of paypal.class.php, a class designed  
 *  to aid in the interfacing between your website, paypal, and the instant
 *  payment notification (IPN) interface.  This single file serves as 4 
 *  virtual pages depending on the "action" varialble passed in the URL. It's
 *  the processing page which processes form data being submitted to paypal, it
 *  is the page paypal returns a user to upon success, it's the page paypal
 *  returns a user to upon canceling an order, and finally, it's the page that
 *  handles the IPN request from Paypal.
 *
 *  I tried to comment this file, aswell as the acutall class file, as well as
 *  I possibly could.  Please email me with questions, comments, and suggestions.
 *  See the header of paypal.class.php for additional resources and information.
*/

// Setup class
require_once('classes/paypal.class.php');  // include the class file
require_once 'jezgro/init.php';
$p = new paypal_class;             // initiate an instance of the class
$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';   // testing paypal url
//$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';     // paypal url

// setup a variable for this script (ie: 'http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal.php')
$this_script = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// if there is not action variable, set the default action of 'process'
if (empty($_GET['action'])) $_GET['action'] = 'process';  

switch ($_GET['action']) {

   case 'process':      // Process and order...

      // There should be no output at this point.  To process the POST data,
      // the submit_paypal_post() function will output all the HTML tags which
      // contains a FORM which is submited instantaneously using the BODY onload
      // attribute.  In other words, don't echo or printf anything when you're
      // going to be calling the submit_paypal_post() function.

      // This is where you would have your form validation  and all that jazz.
      // You would take your POST vars and load them into the class like below,
      // only using the POST values instead of constant string expressions.

      // For example, after ensureing all the POST variables from your custom
      // order form are valid, you might have:
      //
      // $p->add_field('first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
      // $p->add_field('last_name', $_POST['last_name']);

      $p->add_field('business', 'prima@hotmail.rs');
      $p->add_field('return', $this_script.'?action=success');
      $p->add_field('cancel_return', $this_script.'?action=cancel');
      $p->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'?action=ipn');
      $p->add_field('item_name', 'Paypal Test Transaction');
      $p->add_field('amount', '1.99');

      $p->submit_paypal_post(); // submit the fields to paypal
      //$p->dump_fields();      // for debugging, output a table of all the fields
      break;

   case 'success':      // Order was successful...
   DB::getInstance() -> query("INSERT INTO payments(payment_status) VALUES(?)",array(2));
      // This is where you would probably want to thank the user for their order
      // or what have you.  The order information at this point is in POST 
      // variables.  However, you don't want to "process" the order until you
      // get validation from the IPN.  That's where you would have the code to
      // email an admin, update the database with payment status, activate a
      // membership, etc.  

      echo "<html><head><title>Success</title></head><body><h3>Thank you for your order.</h3>";
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { echo "$key: $value<br>"; }
      echo "</body></html>";

      // You could also simply re-direct them to another page, or your own 
      // order status page which presents the user with the status of their
      // order based on a database (which can be modified with the IPN code 
      // below).

      break;

   case 'cancel':       // Order was canceled...

      // The order was canceled before being completed.

      echo "<html><head><title>Canceled</title></head><body><h3>The order was canceled.</h3>";
      echo "</body></html>";

      break;

   case 'ipn':          // Paypal is calling page for IPN validation...

      // It's important to remember that paypal calling this script.  There
      // is no output here.  This is where you validate the IPN data and if it's
      // valid, update your database to signify that the user has payed.  If
      // you try and use an echo or printf function here it's not going to do you
      // a bit of good.  This is on the "backend".  That is why, by default, the
      // class logs all IPN data to a text file.

      if ($p->validate_ipn()) {

         // Payment has been recieved and IPN is verified.  This is where you
         // update your database to activate or process the order, or setup
         // the database with the user's order details, email an administrator,
         // etc.  You can access a slew of information via the ipn_data() array.

         // Check the paypal documentation for specifics on what information
         // is available in the IPN POST variables.  Basically, all the POST vars
         // which paypal sends, which we send back for validation, are now stored
         // in the ipn_data() array.


         // For this example, we'll just email ourselves ALL the data.
         $subject = 'Instant Payment Notification - Recieved Payment';
         $to = 'v-for-vendeta@hotmail.rs';    //  your email
         $body =  "An instant payment notification was successfully recieved\n";
         $body .= "from ".$p->ipn_data['payer_email']." on ".date('m/d/Y');
         $body .= " at ".date('g:i A')."\n\nDetails:\n";

         foreach ($p->ipn_data as $key => $value) { $body .= "\n$key: $value"; }
         mail($to, $subject, $body);
      }
      break;
 }     

?>
```

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/ try IPN process

Answer (score 1):

If `Auto Return` feature is enabled on your account, the buyer should get automatically redirected.
If not, then the buyer has paid through Credit card(note that PayPal does not auto-redirect if payment is made via Credit Card).

Comment: But what to do if my site feil?